# Save two table data into one temporary data to perform CRUD

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to apply CRUD operation on a very simple application that has two tables and those tables are combined using JOIN clause. The thing I am trying to do is to write a **query** that save data from both table into one temporary table and than perform CRUD operation on that temp table and data is updated, deleted, created into both table simultaneously. Here is my code and QUERY

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<DisconnectedModel> dm = new List<DisconnectedModel>();
        string mainconnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mainconnection);
        //string query = "select Patient.CNIC, Patient.Name, PatientVaccina.VaccinationName, PatientVaccine.VaccinationDate from Patient inner join PatientVaccine"

        //string query = "select CNIC, Name from Patient UNION select Cnic, VaccinationName, VaccinationDate, CenterAddress from PatientVaccines";
        //string query = "select * from Patient inner join PatientVaccines on Patient.CNIC, Patient.Name = PatientVaccines.Cnic, PatientVaccines.VaccinationName, PatientVaccines.VaccinationDate, PatientVaccines.CenterAddress";

        string query = "select p.CNIC, p.Name, pv.cnic, pv.VaccinationName, pv.VaccinationDate, pv.CenterAddress from Patient as p join PatientVaccines as pv on p.CNIC = pv.cnic";


        SqlCommand scom = new SqlCommand(query, scon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scom);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            DisconnectedModel dmod = new DisconnectedModel();

            dmod.CNIC = dr["CNIC"].ToString();
            dmod.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            dmod.VaccinationName = dr["VaccinationName"].ToString();
            //dmod.VaccinationDate = dr["VaccinationDate"].ToString();
            dmod.CentreAddress = dr["CenterAddress"].ToString();

            dm.Add(dmod);
            
            
        }

        return View(dm);
    }
```

I am also getting error at `dmod.VaccinationDate = dr["VaccinationDate"].ToString()` data type of this column is DateTime in table.

This query is working fine for me, how to create a temp table that store the record of two tables so that i can perform crud operation on that temp table?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right approach.  If it is temporary data, then why not keep it in memory and then write to DB only when you are finished with your temp operations.

Comment: you have a good point